# MonoTouch: Items saved to /Library/Caches never staying around

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios

My app creates a number of items when first launched and saves them into /Library/Caches/Thumbnails

The app works great.

When I kill the app, then re-run it, those files are not there any more. This does not happen in the simulator.

I have set the no-not-backup attribute, but still when the app runs after being manually shut down, the cache is empty.

Is there a way to have the cache last a bit longer. This is data not created by the user so can't be put into /Documents.

Comment: That's unexpected. I'll try to duplicate this. The **do-not-backup** flag should not change anything since (IIRC) `app/Library/Caches/` is never backed up by iTunes (afaik it's ignored by the simulator too). Could you edit your question to state what version of iOS is being used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code in my `FinishedLaunching` method shows a new file at each execution (both on device and on the simulator).

```
    string appdir = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl.Path;
    string cache = Path.GetFullPath (Path.Combine (appdir, "..", "Library", "Caches"));
    Console.WriteLine ("Files:");
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles (cache, "*.txt"))
             Console.WriteLine ("{0}. {1}", i++, file);
    string fname = Path.Combine (cache, i.ToString () + ".txt");
    File.WriteAllText (fname, "cache this for later");
```

So it looks like iOS [decided to purge](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/local-file-storage-in-ios-5) the data to reclaim some space on your device (new *feature* in iOS 5). This won't happen for every user/devices (if enough space is available) but sadly I do not know how iOS compute this.

**Do-not-backup** won't help (`Caches` is never backed up) unless you save your data inside `Documents` but that could cause you other issues as well (wrt AppStore). For a lack of better answer I suggest you the same as the (previous link) blog author, fill a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).

Comment: The App Store didn't like me using the /Documents and it's disappearing /Caches. Oh well, time to have a new approach. I'm just glad I use MonoTouch so it'll be easy, quick and stable.

Comment: My MonoTouch app was also rejected for use of /Documents to store recreatable images, so I need to switch to Library/Caches as well